# How long for custom events to show up?

Tags: iphone, flurry

I am attempting to add analytics tracking to an iPhone application using Flurry.

I already have Flurry wired up, and it seems to be tracking sessions and usages just fine. However, I just now tried to add a custom event log, but whenever I view the Flurry analytics 'Event' page it tells me that "You are not currently tracking any Events."

In my code I'm calling

`[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"Test_Load"];`

From the Flurry documentation this seems to be correct, but I cannot get any Event data to show up in Flurry. Any idea if I'm just doing this wrong? Or does it sometime take a while before the event data is visible on their website?

Comment: It took 24 hours for my events to show up.

Comment: I'm getting "unknown receiver" when I tried to add this to a file of my own iOS app. I imported "Flurry.h". Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes it takes several hours for your analytics data to show up.

It would seem Flurry isn't exactly "[real time](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html)" after all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Android.
the log appeared roughly 20 mins later on Flurry stats.