# Flurry analytics setup

Tags: ios, objective-c, analytics, flurry

I'm trying to integrate Flurry into my up. 
In AppDelegate.m I have this:

```
[Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
[Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES];
[Flurry startSession:MY_APP_KEY];
```

And here is button action for single view in my test app:

```
- (IBAction)pushButton:(id)sender {
   [Flurry logEvent:@"Some event happaned!"];
}
```

I have all logs:

```
2014-05-19 21:30:28.539 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: startSession called for the first time
2014-05-19 21:30:28.541 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: Start session called with apiKey[49QXRZRCH3KHZBBGN4CZ]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.541 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_136_5.0.0] 
2014-05-19 21:30:28.542 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: crash reporting enabled
2014-05-19 21:30:28.547 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: Trim white space and use apiKey[49QXRZRCH3KHZBBGN4CZ]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.548 FlurryExample[1633:60b] -[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/mariasaveleva/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/49879553-F87C-4C39-98E1-511825EDD96B/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPropertiesData-1119006019_136.archive
2014-05-19 21:30:28.549 FlurryExample[1633:60b] -[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/mariasaveleva/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/49879553-F87C-4C39-98E1-511825EDD96B/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryCkData-1119006019_136.archive
2014-05-19 21:30:28.551 FlurryExample[1633:60b] initial network status [1] ========= 
2014-05-19 21:30:28.552 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: Background session enabled[0]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.554 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Event logging enabled[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.554 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Session reports on close enabled[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.554 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: Finish starting session with apiKey[49QXRZRCH3KHZBBGN4CZ]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.555 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Session reports on pause enabled[0]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.556 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Crash reporting enabled[0]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.561 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Initialized session from scratch with startTime[2014-05-19 17:30:28 +0000]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.561 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Created active session with API[49QXRZRCH3KHZBBGN4CZ]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.562 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Session reports on close enabled[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.563 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Session reports on pause enabled[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.563 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Event logging enabled[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.564 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Crash reporting enabled[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:28.565 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Sending sessions to server, include current NO
2014-05-19 21:30:28.567 FlurryExample[1633:60b] updated network status [1] ======== 
2014-05-19 21:30:28.568 FlurryExample[1633:60b] FlurrySession: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
2014-05-19 21:30:28.572 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Initial timestamp[2014-05-19 17:22:14 +0000] from secure source
2014-05-19 21:30:28.779 FlurryExample[1633:1303] Flurry: start background task
2014-05-19 21:30:28.782 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Scheduled send 0 session(s).
2014-05-19 21:30:29.069 FlurryExample[1633:60b] Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xa68c0f0> { URL: http://data.flurry.com/aas.do } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 122;
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
    Date = "Mon, 19 May 2014 17:30:29 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
} }]
2014-05-19 21:30:29.070 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: async http response code: 200, id [5EAFDA0C-2A68-4DBF-B74D-E3AE7E7550B2]
2014-05-19 21:30:29.072 FlurryExample[1633:1303] -[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/mariasaveleva/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/49879553-F87C-4C39-98E1-511825EDD96B/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPropertiesData-1119006019_136.archive
2014-05-19 21:30:29.073 FlurryExample[1633:1303] -[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/mariasaveleva/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/49879553-F87C-4C39-98E1-511825EDD96B/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryCkData-1119006019_136.archive
2014-05-19 21:30:29.074 FlurryExample[1633:1303] Flurry: stop background task
2014-05-19 21:30:32.247 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Attempting to record Event eventName[Some event happaned!] with parameters[(null)]
2014-05-19 21:30:32.248 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Event count for eventName[Some event happaned!] updated to count[1]
2014-05-19 21:30:32.249 FlurryExample[1633:1303] FlurrySession: Recording event eventName[Some event happaned!] with parameters[(null)] complete
```

Looks like all fine, but I don't have any information about my app in my profile on dev.flurry.com . There is empty session list, empty event list, etc. 
I've tried to wait for hour, make another app with another key - it does not work for me.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is correct. I've had `logEvent:` take up to 3 hours to show online. [Seems others have the same issue, one even up to 24 hrs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406479/how-long-for-custom-events-to-show-up)

Comment: ...and even when logged online in the Flurry console, the API sometimes takes up to several days to reflect the events. Frustrating to say the least :|

Comment: but everyone said that they have at least sessions while waiting events. I don't have even sessions, that's why I think there is some mistakes in my implementation. Btw, thank you for answer, looks like it will be better to continue tomorrow.

Comment: @Maria I have session too, but the Events never really shows up (except 3). I see you are using simulator please ensure that you press the home key to exit the app. The code looks fine. No problem there. i suggest to grab some pop corn and wait :) Cheers